# Can a BLE response be returned in the same connection event?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Using a BLE 4.1 device, can one receive the response to a request (e.g. read request, read blob request) within the same interval?

The task is to read more than 20 bytes in the same connection interval: I am developing an app that needs to read these bytes and display content depending on their value (with very low latency).  I am aware that commands can be stacked within the same connection event, but this is not applicable in this case.

I have been perusing the 4.1 spec without success.  Volume 3, Sections 3.3.2-3.3.3 of spec spec 4.1 specify that no request shall be made before a response is returned.  If it is true that one must wait a connection interval to receive a response, then it take at least 4 connection intervals to read a long attribute (that is more than 20 bytes).

I have found several discussions ([1](https://punchthrough.com/blog/posts/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android), [2](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/32/how-different-ble-packet-types-influence-throughpu/)) on the web implying that a response follows in the next connection event, but I have not found the section of the spec that describes this behavior.

I would appreciate an explanation that cites official documentation, rather than a forum or other website.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES! But in most implementations NO.

In each connection event, master and slave alternate between sending and receiving packets. The master starts by sending a packet, then the slave sends its packet. Both packets may be empty if they have nothing to send. Each packets contains a header bit "more data" (MD) indicating that it would like to send yet another packet. When both the master and slave sets the MD bit to 0 in two consecutive packets, the connection event ends.

This means that in the case the slave sends a request to the master and the master has initially nothing to send, the master first sends an empty packet with MD=0 and the slave sends a packet containing a request with MD=0. In this case the response will not be sent in the same connection event.

However usually the master is also the GATT client. In this case, the master starts by sending a packet containing a request (with MD=0). After the slave receives that packet, it must reply with a packet within exactly 150 (+-2) microseconds. If the firmware is properly programmed to compute the result within this time frame it can send a response packet in the same connection event. I managed to do that myself with a nrf52 chip where I didn't use their softstack but wrote my own code that directly interacted with the RADIO peripheral. I have however so far seen no commercial stacks that manage to do this.

But many firmwares are unfortunately programmed in a way that the data to be sent must be decided even before it starts listening to the master's packet. Such firmwares will not be able to respond in the same connection event. Sometimes however if one of the two ends pushes a lot of data through notifications or write without responses, this will keep the connection event open and then some firmwares can actually send a packet if it arrived to the stack after the connection event started, but before a few packets before the connection event would otherwise end.

Now when we talk about the maximum length of the connection event, there is actually a parameter in the HCI packet "LE Create Connection" called min/max connection event length, where one can hint to the controller how much radio time it should allocate for this connection each interval. Android sets these to 0, which will make Broadcom chips select a short maximum connection event length (like 4-6 packets), but Qualcomm chips will on the other hand allow much longer connection events. If one controls the HCI packets and sets these parameters to equal the connection interval, most chips (including Broadcom) then actually allow the connection event to be as long as the interval. Apple's Core Bluetooth seems to explicitly set the max connection event length to some low value, like 2-4 ms if I'm not forgetting.

I would suggest that you never use the Read Long Characteristic procedure (requiring multiple Read Blob requests and many round trips) but rather simply send a Write to tell the peripheral to, by using notifications, send as much data it needs (and therefore stacking multiple notifications in one connection event).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the option that triggering multiple notifications is in most cases the best option to deliver larger data packets. It has to be noted, though, that the Client will not confirm any notification and thus completeness of data has to be ensured by additional means (a final indication with the number of delivered notifications or similar).